# How to setup webpack 4 for react js with bootstrap4, font-awesome and saas?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, font-awesome, webpack-4

I need help in setting up webpack 4 for react js with bootstrap4, font awesome and sass. I followed the below tutorial to kickstart my project and it worked pretty well, but i want to use bootstrap4 and font awesome as well

https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-4-tutorial/

tried this too, but this is for webpack 3 and some of the dependencies/plugins are not compatible with v4

https://medium.com/@estherfalayi/setting-up-webpack-for-bootstrap-4-and-font-awesome-eb276e04aaeb

i've configured webpack to the best of my knowledge following mutiple guides and tutorials

**webpack.config.js**

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const precss = require('precss');
const path = require('path');

const TransferWebpackPlugin = require('transfer-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js');

var config = {
  entry: [
    APP_DIR + '/index.js',
    'tether',
    'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss'
  ],
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: "js/bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    test: /font-awesome\.config\.js/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'style-loader' },
      { loader: 'font-awesome-loader' }
    ]
    // Bootstrap 4
    {
      test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, use: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      tether: 'tether',
      Tether: 'tether',
      'window.Tether': 'tether',
      Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
      'window.Tether': 'tether',
      Alert: 'exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert',
      Button: 'exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button',
      Carousel: 'exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel',
      Collapse: 'exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse',
      Dropdown: 'exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown',
      Modal: 'exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal',
      Popover: 'exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover',
      Scrollspy: 'exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy',
      Tab: 'exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab',
      Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
      Util: 'exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util'
    }),
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: any error with above config ?

Comment: Yeah with font-awesome module, I'm not sure if the above config is correct

Answer (score 1):

Some webpack plugin haven't support webacpk4. html-webpack-plugin need to use beta version.

Here is my solution to use webpack4.
https://github.com/Rukeith/blog-website/blob/develop/webpack.common.js

Comment: That link is broken